# Can I customize my controls exactly the way I want them?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I cannot play with the default controller layout at all.  Having to press the left joystick to run is awful and none of the presets are any better.

Is there really such a game in the year 2013 that doesn't let you program each button to the command you want?

Comment: PC gaming allows you to customize completely, try using a mouse instead of a controller if it's really that bad for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most console games don't allow the full customization of the controls, to build upon this I am willing to say that ALL fps' have strict control setups built into the game. Although, I can be wrong. To answer your question, yes, BO2 doesn't allow full controller editing.